# Question about finding a divergent series with cosine

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am new on StackExchange. I have a question about series : can we find two sequences of numbers $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$  and $(b_n)_{n\geq 1}$ satisfying the following two conditions :

A) $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty} a_n=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty} b_n=0$. I need here $b_n>0$.

B) for any fixed integer $m\geq 1$, the series $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1} \frac{a_n}{n} \cos(n b_m)$ is divergent

Can someone have an idea ?

Comment due to the answers below :

- the sequence $(a_n)$ cannot be decreasing. More generally, the sequence $(\frac{a_n}{n})$ cannot be decreasing. Actually the classical Abel summation would show that the series $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1} \frac{a_n}{n} \cos(n b_m)$ is convergent (because the partial sums of $\sum\limits_{n\geq 1} \cos(n b_m)$ are uniformly bounded although the bound depends on $m$).

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried an obvious sequence, like $b_n = \frac 1n$, for example?

Comment: For the choice $b_n=1/n$ I do not know. But $a_n=1/log(n)$ cannot work because it is decreasing (I will add a comment on my question).

Comment: If $a_n$ positive and isn't deacreasing, how $\lim_{n \to +\infty}a_n  = 0$?

Comment: It is actually possible but I think I will not need the positivity assumption on $a_n$. I change my statement.